# customize bash prompt based on groups

Tags: bash

I am trying to customize the bash prompt based on a users group, but am not sure how to approach it.

For those in the devel group, I want the export PS1= to be:

```
 "[\u@\h\[$(tput setaf 3)\]\[$(tput bold)\](devel) \[$(tput sgr0)\]\W]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

and for those in infra I want it to be:

```
 "[\u@\h\[$(tput setaf 3)\]\[$(tput bold)\](infra) \[$(tput sgr0)\]\W]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

and for everyone else, I want it to use the default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `.bashrc` for each group that sets the prompt

in etc/profile:

`` if [ `id -ng` = "some_group" ] ; then
    # load group bashrc
fi ``

Comment: `/etc/profile` is the wrong place this, as it can be sourced by shells other than `bash` (and is only sourced by login shells). An interactive `bash` session *only* reads `.bashrc` on startup

Comment: (A system might provide a file such as `/etc/bashrc` that can be sourced by `~/.bashrc`, though.)

Comment: In Debian there seems to be `/etc/bash.bashrc`: `# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.`

Comment: And also, `id -g` prints the effective group id. You should probably have different groups for different user groups, like `dev` for developers and then: `if [[ $(id -nG) == *" dev "*]]; then ...`.

Comment: Thank you all. ended up dropping appropriate if/then's in the profile.local file that was being sourced on the system and all is working well.